# How to test jdbc method with Junit?

Tags: java, testing, jdbc, mockito, junit5

I want to test my method in Junit5 with Mockito framework. But i am beginner of programming and don't know how should i do it correctly ?

This is my function which i want to test:

```
 public boolean sprawdzIlosc(){
    try {
        String sumujProdukty ="SELECT SUM(ilosc) AS podliczenie FROM produkty";

        connection = ConnectionManager.connectionOthers();
        if (connection == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Brak połączenia z bazą danych");
        }
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sumujProdukty);
        if(resultSet.next()) {
            ilosc = resultSet.getInt(1);
            return true;
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException("Wyjątek związany z błędną składnią SQL");
    }
    finally {
        if (resultSet != null) {
            try {
                resultSet.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) { /* */}
        }
        if (statement != null) {
            try {
                statement.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) { /* */}
        }
        if (connection != null) {
            try {
                connection.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) { /* */}
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

And this is test for my function which not work correctly:

```
class ProductDaoTest {
@Mock
private ProductDao productDao;
@Mock
private DataSource dataSource;

@Mock
private Connection connection;

@Mock
private Statement statement;

@Mock
private ResultSet resultSet;

private ProductBean produkt;

@Before
public void setUp() throws SQLException {
    assertNotNull(dataSource);
    when(dataSource.getConnection()).thenReturn(connection);
    when(connection.createStatement()).thenReturn(statement);
    when(statement.executeQuery("SELECT SUM(ilosc) AS podliczenie FROM produkty")).thenReturn(resultSet);
    when(resultSet.next()).thenReturn(true);
}
@Test
public void testSprawdzIlosc(){
assertTrue(productDao.sprawdzIlosc());
    }
```

I need some advice on how to test a function using a database. Thanks in advance.

Comment: An alternative would be to test using an in-memory database such as HSQLDB

Comment: You need to test with a database for this. spring-boot comes with h2 set up for you and makes writing tests easy. there is also a project called dbunit that helps with unit test data setup and verification. mocking jdbc objects like this will be a lot of work and not do anything worthwhile. btw putting jdbc objects in instance scope is a bad idea. they should be local variables in the method. otherwise you will have trouble when different threads access the method concurrently.

Comment: Don't mock JDBC. It is hard to do correctly, and you are probably testing more whether you mocked JDBC correctly, then testing the code you want to test. Either connect to a real database (eg using test-containers-java), or consider not testing this part in unit tests.